# how to include source code in the debian package

Tags: debian, python-packaging

I have build a debian package for my python application using make-deb and dh-virtualenv and installed it. But i was unable to find the source code for the application in the `/usr/shar/python/<apckage_name>`  location.

I know it is not the correct way to include the source code along with binaries, but i have a requirement in which i have to interpolation at the machine where the code is being deployed.

I have also tried the stdeb module from standard library but it doesn't package your dependencies in a virtualenv.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As you wrote, it is really non standard, so you should use non-standard methods. E.g. using `dh_movefiles` to copy also the sources